# iOS Push Notification inside proprietary framework

Tags: ios

I need to distribute a framework.

This frameworks needs silent notifications to update his configuration in background.

For my understanding it seems not possible because push configuration setup is done on the application level. (And in my case, I do not manage the application push certificate)

Is there any solution to push a notification to my framework ?

Comment: There is no way to do it automagically. Can't you just instruct your users to forward notifications somewhere into your class instance?

Comment: It is more difficult... My own framework is using a push server and the application using my framework is not obliged to setup a push configuration. Push feature is only required for my framework (silent notification)

Comment: Your framework is not an app. To be able to receive push notifications, the app should be properly configured in apple developer account. The app should have a push certificate for a specific App ID. Your only way is to force this application to register for push notifications